# Bisector Equality

Tags: geometry

In $\Delta ABC$, let points $P$ and $Q$ be on side $AC$ such that $AP+BC=AB+CQ$. Let $R$ be the midpoint of $PQ$, and suppose that $BR$ is the bisector of $\angle ABC$. Show that $\Delta ABC$ is an isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 1):

By [Angle-Bisector Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) $$\frac{AR}{RC}=\frac{AB}{BC}$$ and by addendo $$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{AB+AR}{BC+RC}=1$$ according to your problem. Hence $AB=BC$ and the triangle is isosceles.

Comment: Can you explain why AB + AR = ... = BC + RC so that the ratio of them is equal to 1?

Answer (score 0):

First, suppose that we have $A,P,Q, C$ on the edge $AC$ in this order.

Let $s,t,u$ be the length of $AP, CQ, PR$.

Since $BR$ is the bisector of $\angle ABC$, 
$$AB : BC=AR : CR.$$
Hence, there exists a $k\gt0\in\mathbb R$ such that 
$$AB=k(s+u), BC=k(u+t).$$

Now, since $AP+BC=AB+CQ,$ we have
$$s+k(u+t)=t+k(s+u)\iff (s-t)(k-1)=0.$$

1) The $s=t$ case immediately leads our conclusion since we have $AR=CR$.

2) The $k=1$ case leads that $CB=CR, AB=AR$. This leads that $\angle CRB=\angle ARB=90^\circ.$ Hence, we get our conclusion.

Even if we have $A, Q, P, C$ on the edge $AC$ in this order, then you can repeat the almost same argument as above. **Q.E.D.**